# Spring security open specific paths publicly with Oauth

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth

In the API I am developing almost every path should be oauth protected, with a few examples. Right now I managed to protect every path using the addFilterBefore function:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
            .addFilterBefore(zeroLeggedOAuthProviderProcessingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("OAUTH");
}
```

What I would like to do is open some paths (e.g. /languages) for everybody, while locking up every other path.

Could someone show me how this is done? Or perhaps someone can explain the concept of filters to me?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  In the same class @Override configure again, like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers('/languages/**');
}
```

Should no longer require OAUTH for any endpoints under /languages